# How to read the queue name in Sidekiq worker?

Tags: sidekiq

I'm using recursive worker invocations to process a large set of data. If I start the worker with

```
MyWorker.set(queue: 'important').perform_async
```

How can I make the following invocations to use the same queue? Below is my worker which currently sends the following invocations to the default queue. In order to set the queue, I need to read it from somewhere. Or send it also as a parameter, which seems redundant.

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    DataQueue.processable_entities.first(100).each(&:process)
    MyWorker.perform_async if DataQueue.processable_entities.exists?
  end
end
```

Comment: Jobs are meant to be orthogonal to queues. An executing job cannot tell what queue it was enqueued to.

Comment: Thanks @MikePerham. Then I need to send it also as a parameter.